# jQuery popover doesn't show appended html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with my popover.
Because I want to avoid ID conflicts, I try to remove the html code from its original position when It gets shown in the popover.
When the popover gets closed / hidden, I copy the code back to it's original positon.

My problem is, that if I show the popover, hide the popover and want to show the popover again, the popover is empty.
But when I debug my code, the html which is determined in the content section of the popover seems to be correct.

Here is my code:

```
 jQuery('.dashboard_popper_btn').popover({
    placement: 'bottom',
    container: 'body',
    html: true,
    template: '<div class="my-dashboard-popover popover">'+
                '<div class="arrow"></div>'+
                '<div class="popover-inner">'+
                '<h3 class="popover-title"></h3>'+
                '<div class="popover-content">'+
                '<p></p></div></div></div>',        
    content: function () {
        var html;
        var popoverContent  = jQuery(this).data("popoverContent");
        var currentPopper   = jQuery(this).parent().find('.popper-content'); 
        if (jQuery(currentPopper).length > 0) {
            html            = jQuery(currentPopper).html();
        }
        if (typeof html !== typeof undefined && html != "undefined") {
            jQuery(this).data("popoverContent", currentPopper);
            jQuery(currentPopper).remove();
        } else if (popoverContent != null) {
            html        = jQuery(popoverContent).html();
        }
        //html = jQuery.parseHTML(String(html));

        return html;
    }
}).on('hide.bs.popover', function() {
    var contentId       = "#"+jQuery(this).attr("aria-describedby");
    var currentPopover  = jQuery(contentId);
    var popoverContent  = jQuery(contentId).find(".popover-content");       
    jQuery(this).data("popoverContent", popoverContent);
}).on('hidden.bs.popover', function() {
    var parent          = jQuery(this).parent();
    var popoverContent = jQuery(this).data("popoverContent");
    jQuery(popoverContent).addClass("popper-content");
    jQuery(popoverContent).addClass("rsib_hide");
    jQuery(popoverContent).removeClass("popover-content");
    jQuery(popoverContent).appendTo(parent);
});
```

As I said, when I debug the code everything seems to be fine. Even the HTML looks fine after I reinsert the code.

Following the relevant HTML Code:

```
<div class="dashboard_filter_row">
<a class="dashboard_popper_btn" data-toggle="popover" data-original-title="" title="">Filter</a>
<div class="popper-content rsib_hide">
    <div class="ibfc_checkbox_table_dropdown_container">
        <div class="ibfc_checkbox_table_dropdown_button ibui_select ibui_select_popover_accordeon">
            Months 
            <div style="text-align: right; float: right; margin-right: 20px;">
                <input id="dashboard_check_all_months_3250558b0140595dc1" class="my_checkbox" type="checkbox">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="month_selection" style="display: none;">
            <ul>
                <li class="table_active_kz">
                    <input class="cb_months_dd_check_table_active ibfc_table_dropdop_checkbox" value="1" name="cb_months_dd_check_table_active" type="checkbox">
                    <span>Januar</span>
                </li>
                <li class="table_active_kz">
                    <input class="cb_months_dd_check_table_active ibfc_table_dropdop_checkbox" value="2" name="cb_months_dd_check_table_active" type="checkbox">
                    <span>Februar</span>
                </li>
                <li class="table_active_kz">
                    <input class="cb_months_dd_check_table_active ibfc_table_dropdop_checkbox" value="3" name="cb_months_dd_check_table_active" type="checkbox">
                    <span>März</span>
                </li>
                <!-- ... -->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add your HTML code as well to the question

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I Have added the relevant html code.

Answer (score 0):

ive created a snippet to get it working easy.

```
//Show on enter
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".MYCLASS", function() {

    $(this).popover({
        container: 'body',
        html: true,
        placement: 'bottom', //top,bottom,left,right
        content: function () {
            return '<b>My content</b>'; //HTML content
        }
    });

    $(this).popover('show');
});

//Remove after leave
$(document).on("mouseleave", ".MYCLASS", function() {

    $(this).popover('destroy');

});
```

With this maybe u can play with ur code.